# SQLFiddle - Oracle 11g - unable to create schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlfiddle

I am trying to create a table in SQLFiddle using Oracle and I want to specify the schema the table belongs to.

However I am having a tough time making the schema. Since given the code below:

```
CREATE USER myname
  IDENTIFIED BY pwd4myname
  DEFAULT TABLESPACE tbs_perm_01
  TEMPORARY TABLESPACE tbs_temp_01
  QUOTA 20M on tbs_perm_01;

GRANT create session TO myname;
GRANT create table TO myname;
GRANT create view TO myname;
GRANT create any trigger TO myname;
GRANT create any procedure TO myname;
GRANT create sequence TO myname;
GRANT create synonym TO myname;


CREATE TABLE myname_schema.person (
         person_id      NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
         name       VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
         phone        NUMBER(9),
         address        VARCHAR2(10),
         );
```

When running this I am getting:

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Comment: That's not what SQLFiddle is for.  The sandbox is not that large.

Answer (score 0):

This is sandboxed environment with limited privileges. You can't create your own user.

[image]

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7860/0)**

```
SELECT * FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Log in as SYSDBA, and issue the command,

GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO YOUR_USER_NAME;

Logoff from the SYSDBA, and again log in with your user name, now try to create table.

Comment: You did see that this is a SQLFiddle-specific question, right?  Additionally, you should never recommend to login as `SYSDBA` to perform these kinds of tasks.

Comment: Well, he is using SQL fiddle for demonstration purpose, eventually he will going to use this on his server. Yes, I agree that it is not recommended to use SYSDBA, but we can go with SYSOPER. I'm sorry if I have disappointed you with my answer previously. Thank you for correcting me.